# Docker maven and jenkins, mvn install failed requesting junit:junit:jar:3.x

Tags: maven, jenkins, docker

I have a maven 3.2.5 docker image and a jenkins image built from the maven image.

Maven image Dockerfile:

```
from dockerfile/java:oracle-java7


ENV MAVEN_VERSION 3.2.5
RUN curl -sSL http://mirror.bit.edu.cn/apache/maven/maven-3/$MAVEN_VERSION/binaries/apache-maven-$MAVEN_VERSION-bin.tar.gz | tar xzf - -C /usr/share \
&& mv /usr/share/apache-maven-$MAVEN_VERSION /usr/share/maven \
&& ln -s /usr/share/maven/bin/mvn /usr/bin/mvn
#ADD settings.xml /usr/share/maven/conf/
ENV MAVEN_HOME /usr/share/maven
CMD ["mvn"]
```

Jenkins Dockerfile:

```
from javcly/fongwell:maven
RUN mkdir -p /data/jenkins && mkdir -p /var/lib/jenkins
RUN touch /data/jenkins/jenkins.log


ADD jenkins.war /var/lib/jenkins/
VOLUME /data/jenkins
ENV JENKINS_HOME /data/jenkins

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["java","-jar","/var/lib/jenkins/jenkins.war","--webroot=/data/jenkins","--logfile=/data/jenkins/jenkins.log"]
```

then I start the jenkins image with the command:

```
docker run -d -v /data/docker/jenkins:/data/jenkins -v /usr/share/maven-repo:/root/.m2/repository  --name jenkins -p 27099:8080 --add-host git.mydomain.com:192.168.0.119  docker:jenkins
```

as above, `/root/.m2/repository` on the container is mounted to /usr/share/maven-repo on the host machine

now I set up my project on Jenkins and pull down source code from Git, run

```
mvn clean install -X
```

it gives me this error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) on project infrastrucure: Execution default-install of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4:install failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact junit:junit:jar:3.x in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) on project infrastrucure: Execution default-install of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4:install failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact junit:junit:jar:3.x in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:224)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:355)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:160)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-install of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4:install failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact junit:junit:jar:3.x in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:104)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact junit:junit:jar:3.x in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.createPluginRealm(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:361)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.setupPluginRealm(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:329)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.getPluginRealm(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:229)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:100)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not find artifact junit:junit:jar:3.x in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:367)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:200)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find artifact junit:junit:jar:3.x in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ArtifactTransportListener.transferFailed(ArtifactTransportListener.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:355)
    at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:67)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

If I build the same project on the host machine directly, it is SUCCESSFUL!

Running `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=junit` gave me the same error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) on project infrastrucure: Execution default-cli of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact junit:junit:jar:3.x in nexus-osc (http://maven.oschina.net/content/groups/public/) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: Can you share your pom.xml file please?

Comment: pom.xml added. cheerss

Answer (score 0):

3.x isn't a version as such, so there is nothing to find. You need to replace the x with a concrete number.

See here for a list of versions: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit

An example for your pom would be:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>3.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: pom.xml added. i don't think i have junit:junit:3.x in the pom or the dependent libraries have it.

Comment: You can find out what is pulling in Junit dependencies using `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=junit`